# Organize XML files in Spring Integration project

Tags: spring-integration

We would like to split our Spring Integration config in several files, for example `flow-one.xml` and `flow-two.xml`. In each such file we would like to have an `input` channel.

Can Spring Integration automatically prefix the channel id with the XML file name, i.e. `flow-one.input` and `flow-two.input`?

How else would you handle the XML configuration (without resorting to one large XML file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Spring Integration Flow](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-flow) extension project, it encapsulates sub flows and makes them "callable".

Otherwise you have to manage your channel naming to prevent overlaps.

Comment: I saw the Spring Integration Flow project, but I don't want sub flows. So I guess I have to make the make my ids manually unique.